# Recent IE update / HTML 4.0 Transitional doctype

Tags: internet-explorer

I think an IE11 update in the last 3 weeks has affected a page in our web application that is set to a compatability mode using the tag !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"

Most problems have so far been based around jquery selectors not working, i.e. not selecting elements that are available on the page when using id ends with e.g. $("input[id$='myInput']" ) and className selectors e.g. $(".myInputClasss" )

We've also had a problem unrelated to jquery but its something that has just started happening so again I am assuming it is related to an IE update combined with the compatability mode of the page whereby an html anchor tag does not work without having any innerHTML set. If the innerHTML for the tag is empty the hyperlink doesn't work, if I add any text(as a workaround I've added a single underscrore) it works ok.

The problems are occurring in a legacy ASP.Net web forms app, we only support IE for this app. We are using jquery 1.4.2. There have been no changes made to the application in the last 12 months. We've put workarounds in for all the issues so far but are expecting there possibly to be more.

Has any body had any similar issues or can shed any light that would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mat,

We just had a similar situation with IE 11 and Edge.  We have a site that specifies that exact Doctype.  What we noticed yesterday is that it was converting that doctype into an HTML 5 doctype causing some of the layout to look different and we couldn't see our in-line styles. (Yeah, I know, don't start.  It wasn't my code).

When we ran it today, all was corrected and it recognized our doctype and we could again see our styles in the Developer Tools.

I know this doesn't answer your question but I have noticed some odd behavior.